# Function with bidimensional array as parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters

I read that to declare a function with a bidimensional array as parameter, I need to specify the number of columns of the array, but if I don't know the size of the matrix I need to use double pointer. However, I can't understand this process very well, can someone give me some short and simple example of this type of function?

Thank you

Also, I tried to write a program but it gives me some warning.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int diagonal(int**,int );--->first note

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int array[N][N];
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("Insert the numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            scanf("%d",&array[i][i]);
          }
    }
    diagonal(&array[N][N],N); ---->second warning
}

int diagonal(int**A,int N){
    int i;
    int condition=0;
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
       if(A[0][0]!=A[i+1][i+1]){
          return -1;
       }else{
          condition=1;
       }
   }
   if(condition==1){
      int val=A[i][i];
      int sum= N*val;
      return sum;
   }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
3|note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int *'|

17|warning: passing argument 1 of 'diagonal' from incompatible pointer type|


||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

The program should scan a matrix and return the sum of elements on the main diagonal if the elements on the diagonal have the same value
return -1 if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a variable size array as an argument, you need to specify the size first, then use that parameter as the array size in the array argument:

```
int diagonal(int N, int A[N][N] );

int main() {
    ...
    diagonal(N, array);
}

int diagonal(int N, int A[N][N]){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if the question may sounds dumb,but i'm a beginner.In the declaration shoudn't i delete the "N" parameters? i mean if i put 

int diagonal(int N, int A[N][N] ); 

the compiler says that "N" is undeclared and if i delete "N" the program won't run

Comment: @GiorgioM.  In most cases, the parameter names in a declaration are not required, but in this case it's needed to let the compiler know it's dealing with a variable sized array and what specifies the size.  Attempting to declare the array parameter as `int [][]` is an incomplete declaration.

Comment: Ahhh nevermind now it works .
Thank you so much 
and thank you to all the people that answered

Answer (score 1):

> 17|warning: passing argument 1 of 'diagonal' from incompatible pointer type|

```
diagonal(&array[N][N],N); //---->warning
```

here `&array[N][N]` is of the type `int*` but your function definition:

int diagonal(int**,int );

has first argument type as `int**` so **you are sending wrong type as an argument**. that's the reason why you are get this warning.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your array wrong. You should pass `array` instead of `&array[N][N]`. When you do `&array[N][N]` you just get address of [N][N] array's element and pass it, it is invalid address.

```
diagonal(array, N);
```

Also, when you do scanf, you, probably wanted to get `[i][j]` element, but you do `[i][i]` two times.

```
scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
```